# Django: Formset for adding captions to uploaded images

Tags: python, django, image, django-forms

I'm using Django and am trying to implement, what I would assume, is a fairly common feature in image uploads. I want to generate a `formset` (maybe `modelformset`?) for adding a caption to each Image that a user has just uploaded (similar to a "review the images you just uploaded" page).

**This is the basic idea:**

I have a simple form for submitting one or more images at once:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': 'multiple'}))
```

It produces this:

[image]

Then, in the view, I do some handling/processing for each image from the POST, and store a resized version of the image as an instance of a model, called `ImageItem`:

```
class ImageItem(models.Model):
    resized_img = models.ImageField(upload_to=img_get_file_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)      
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=1000,
                               blank=True)
```

(Here is the `UploadImage` view, for reference...notice that as soon as the form is validated and the images have been saved in the *handle_uploaded_image* function, it redirects to a view for adding a caption to all the images.)

```
def UploadImageToLibrary(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_image(form) # creates new sizes of images, saves resized version as ImageItem instances
            return AddInfoForImage(request) # SEND USER TO A PAGE FOR ADDING CAPTIONS TO EACH IMAGE...not sure what this next view should contain...?
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()
    return render_to_response('upload_item.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---

*Okay, now comes the part I need help with....*

As soon as the images save, I want the next view to generate a form for each image that has been uploaded, so that users can add a caption to the image. When they're done adding all the information to all the new images, they hit `submit`, and each caption is saved to the appropriate ImageItem instance. I don't know how many forms should be created, that depends on how many images the user uploaded. Below is a visual representation of what I want the formset to do (ignore the other stuff, we can continue using a simple caption as an example):

[image]

---

Specifically, this is the stuff I need help with:

- I don't know how to supply the appropriate amount of `CaptionForm`s, based on how many images the user just uploaded.
- I don't know how to place the appropriate `ImageItem.resized_img` to the left of the form that it's referencing in the template.
- I don't know how to make sure that once the `CaptionForm`s are submitted, that I save the captions to the appropriate `ImageItem` instance.

I would imagine all three of these points can somehow be addressed in one `formset` or `modelformset` solution?

---

***Like I said, this seems like a very common situation. If anyone knows of any existing code that does this, please let me know. Thanks!***

Comment: You probably want to look into form wizards.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Thanks, looking into them now... Would they allow me to query the resized images that were posted on the first page of the wizard from the second page of the wizard? Or do all the forms of the wizard have to post at the very end?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with them to tell you this. I just put it out there because multi-step processes are usually a job for wizards! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) and to access resized image in template `{{ form.instance.resized_img }}`